# Developing model theory in the language of PA

Tags: model-theory, axioms, proof-theory, peano-axioms, finitism

Is it possible to develop model theory for models of $PA$, inside $PA$ itself (augmented with consistency raising assumptions such as $Con(ZFC)$ if necessary, but still in the language of $PA$)? What would this look like?

When working in ZFC, it is relatively easy to talk about $\mathbb{N}$ as a model of $PA$, because it is an object in the theory, but in $PA$ there is no such object, and the truth predicate for formulas of $PA$ cannot be defined. So it seems like model theory can't really even get off the ground. So what is "the finitist's answer" to model theory as a field of mathematics?

Comment: Note that there's nothing really special about model theory here: PA can't directly treat infinite structures in general, so no mathematics treating infinite entities goes through "directly" in PA. For example, how should PA understand the Heine-Borel theorem?

Comment: @NoahSchweber There is a decent literature on how much of analysis can be done "indirectly" in PA. You get a nice language by moving to conservative second order extensions like ACA0, and then you can talk about various kinds of infinite structures as second order objects. For example, https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Papers/elementary.pdf talks about doing analysis in EA, which is a pretty weak subsystem of PA.

Comment: But that all applies equally well to model theory - in particular, ACA$_0$ proves the completeness theorem and the bivalence of truth. Uncountable structures aren't directly treatable in ACA$_0$ but we can just repeat the same trick and go to yet another conservative extension (cf. "higher-order reverse mathematics"). What *new* difficulty does model theory pose?

Comment: @Noah It's not clear to me how to define the truth predicate of PA, as I mentioned. It's not hard to extend the *language* to higher order things (I suspect that you eventually end up with some kind of constructive type theory if you take this approach to its conclusion), and *provability* in these extensions is compensated by additional consistency strengthening in the original base theory $PA$. As far as I am aware this handles the technical restrictions, but it would still be helpful to see what the overall process looks like and what comes out at the end.

Comment: ... Model theory is an example, used because it is easily accessible from a proof theory point of view and has some obviously interesting theorems that go up against Godel's theorems without care.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the truth predicate of PA." A theory doesn't have a truth predicate, a *structure* does. In the language of second-order arithmetic, "$\models$" has an obvious $\Sigma^1_1$ definition ("There is a family of Skolem functions such that ...") and ACA$_0$ can prove many basic facts about it. For example, ACA$_0$ can directly state and prove "If PA has a model then PA + $\neg$Con(PA) has a model."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Aha, I didn't realize that this "skolem function" definition works. If you could expound on that with references or an answer I would like that. (In particular, what PA statement does it correspond to, and what are the basic facts provable in PA/ACA0, and what is needed to prove the facts that we care about, such as soundness and completeness?)

Comment: Sure, will do (although I vaguely recall answering this question before - let me see if I can find it ...).

Comment: So I found what I was looking for; it doesn't really answer this question, but I think it's still relevant so I'm going to link it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259400/ideal-treatment-of-set-theory-as-a-meta-theory-for-developing-first-order-logic/3259546#3259546).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[This old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259400/ideal-treatment-of-set-theory-as-a-meta-theory-for-developing-first-order-logic/3259546#3259546) is related.*

---

The usual approach - of shifting to an appropriate conservative extension - works fine here. The key observation is that a statement of the form "$M\models\varphi$" is best understood as an existential quantification over objects one type higher than $M$ (namely, "there is a family of Skolem functions for $\varphi$ in $M$").

In particular, this means that $ACA_0$ - the usual go-to expansion of PA - can directly talk about *countable* model theory: the structures we look at are coded by sets of natural numbers, and "$\models$" is a $\Sigma^1_1$ relation. $ACA_0$ is strong enough to prove basic facts about model theory under this approach; in particular, it proves compactness/completeness (this actually only takes $WKL_0$, which is of strictly weaker consistency strength) and "weak" bivalence: the scheme consisting of, for each sentence $\varphi$, the sentence "For each $M$ we have $M\models\varphi$ or $M\models\neg\varphi$." On the other hand, there are some basic principles $ACA_0$ can't prove:

- "Strong" bivalence - the single sentence "For every sentence $\varphi$ and every structure $M$ we have $M\models\varphi$ or $M\models\neg\varphi$" - is equivalent over $RCA_0$ to the statement "For every $X,n$, the $n$th jump of $X$ exists," which is strictly stronger than $ACA_0$. *(If I recall correctly this theory is denoted "$ACA_0^*$.")* A key point here is the computability-theoretic analysis of Skolem functions: we show that we can build Skolem functions uniformly from the appropriate number of Turing jumps.
- "Every structure has a theory" is even stronger: it's equivalent over $RCA_0$ to $ACA_0^+$, which is $RCA_0$ + "For every $X$, the $\omega$th jump of $X$ exists." *(The point is that $Th(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot,X)$ "is" just $X^{(\omega)}$.)*

And of course there's the fact that this still doesn't let us handle *uncountable* structures directly, which are important. But that's also an issue with mathematics in general - we just need to look for higher-order conservative extensions (like higher reverse mathematics' $RCA_0^\omega+\mathcal{E}_1$).

---

At this point it's worth mentioning some work of Victor Harnik:

- [In $1985$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2273795.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A5cf9eccfaf01576b7700e15f0ce64497), Harnik studied the reverse math of some theorems of model theory ...
- [but in $1987$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007287900029?via%3Dihub) he passed to a richer language to handle uncountable structures.

Barring some unpublished notes of Harvey Friedman from the late $70$s, I believe this was the earliest work in higher-order reverse mathematics; however, it was not followed up on at the time to the best of my knowledge, and [the modern approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#Use_of_higher-order_arithmetic) looks rather different.

Comment: This brings something I had not realized was important to the fore: ACA${}_0$ is not a definitional extension of PA, it is "merely" a conservative extension, and in particular formulas with existential quantifiers cannot be rendered in PA. Since the formula $M\vDash\varphi$ in question is $\Sigma_1^1$, it can be rendered as $\exists F,\psi(F,M,n)$ where $n$ is a code for $\varphi$ and $M$ and $F$ are second order variables, which in PA is equivalent to the existence of a definable formula $F(a)$ such that $\psi[F,M](n)$. But this means PA can only express $M\vDash_F\varphi$ for fixed $M,F$...

Comment: @MarioCarneiro But that's true, for exactly the same reason, of all infinite objects. Again, what singles model theory out here?

Comment: I'm fine with the fact that this is schematic over $M$ and $F$, but I'm trying to work my head around the existential part. What would a theorem using the relation look like? You mention weak bivalence: that seems to mean that you are proving $(M\vDash_F\varphi)\lor(M\vDash_G\neg\varphi)$ where $F$ and $G$ are specific expressions in terms of $M$ and $\varphi$?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro No, the instance of weak bivalence corresponding to a given $\varphi$ is "For all $M$, either $M\models\varphi$ or $M\models\neg\varphi$" - or in your notation, "$\forall M(\exists F(M\models_F\varphi)\vee\exists G(M\models_G\varphi))$." This is a sentence in the language of second-order arithmetic. But again, we have to do this linguistic shift *any* time we talk about infinite objects; there's nothing special about model theory here.

Comment: ACA0 is conservative over PA, but I'm trying to figure out more syntactically what the content of that assertion is in order to get a definition in PA itself. $M\vDash_F\varphi$ says that $F$ is a set of skolem functions validating that $M\vDash\varphi$. I'm trying to figure out what theorem or set of theorems of PA correspond to this assertion in second order logic. I think that it says that given any $M$, you can provide $F$ and $G$ such that $PA\vdash M\vDash_F\varphi\lor M\vDash_G\neg\varphi$, but I could be wrong. I looked at Simpson's book but the conservativity proof is nonconstructive.

Comment: I think looking for a "PA-counterpart" in the first place misses the point of passing to a conservative extension: we're trying to *gain* expressive power. Why should anything we're talking about in this newer language have a PA-counterpart, whatever that means? (And again this isn't special to model theory - e.g. what's the PA-counterpart of "$[0,1]$ is compact"?)

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean when you say that the conservativity proof is non-constructive. It's completely constructive: if $A$ is a model of PA then $(A,Def(A))$ is a model of ACA$_0$.

Comment: What I mean is that it's a model theoretic proof rather than a proof theoretic proof, so it is difficult to see how to turn a proof of $ACA_0\vdash\varphi$ where $\varphi$ is arithmetic into a proof of $PA\vdash\varphi$, and what kind of damage is done to the proof in the process. I found https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127080/what-metatheory-proves-mathsfaca-0-conservative-over-pa indicating that the proof grows superexponentially, but I haven't managed to track down the sources for this yet.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro But that issue is irrelevant here since our $\varphi$s aren't arithmetic (that's sort of the point).

Comment: Right, it doesn't totally answer the question, my hope was actually to track down the sources and see what they have to say about the non-arithmetic statements. At the risk of tipping my hand as to my motivation, in my work I am interested in PA extended with schematic variables, which gives it essentially the expressive power of ACA_0 without the existential second order variables. I suspect that model theory such as this is still accessible, but you would have to define some specific terms $F[M]$ and $G[M]$ and prove bivalence with respect to them.

Comment: Regarding "we're trying to gain expressive power", I don't really think of it that way. I just want to circumvent the pedant that says "you can't define the set of prime numbers in PA" when $n\in \mathbb{P}$ is perfectly well definable; I just want a language that puts "sugar over PA" so that it's not a ridiculous question to have PA "talk about infinite sets" that are just formulas with one free variable coding subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. I have been using ACA_0 as a proxy for this when talking to logicians, but it seems that it might be too strong.